# HA and load balancing httpd with HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, httpd

I'm working on an infrastructure where http traffic is reverse proxied by httpd servers. We would like to stay on httpd (instead of considering, for example, Nginx) because we have many virtual hosts configured on this platform.

Now I would like to add HA and load balancing features to the reverse proxy part. If I create an active-active cluster, I need a solution like DNS round robin, which I would like not to consider as my first option (because it is complicated to obtain).

Would it be a good solution, configuring an HAProxy active-passive cluster (with floating ip), load balancing (in tcp mode, level 4) an httpd active-active cluster, doing the real http(s) reverse proxying?
In this way I would achieve the following:

1. HA. HAProxy is fault-tolerant so as the httpd's
2. Load Balancing. Httpd are load balanced (active-active). HAProxy is not (one single host is active), but I make the assumption, it will scale better than httpd in handling traffic, with one node being sufficient
3. Having HAProxy load balancing in tcp, I can leave all the http and https configuration on the httpd side.

Are there any drawbacks with this approach, or better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Sai,

Sounds like you have come up with a sensible solution. You're describing a typical HA load balancer deployment for an application cluster. HAProxy gives you a lot of flexibility if and when you need it, and TCP pass-through mode is nice and simple.

The only problem is the added complexity of reliably maintaining an HAProxy cluster.
I assume you'll use Keepalived?

Here at Loadbalancer.org we currently use Heartbeat (HA-Linux), but will be shortly be moving to our own Pulse HA system with supports active/active across multiple load balancers.